# Windows Authentication Roles

Tags: windows-authentication

I have created an MVC4 Web App with Windows Auth.  Is it possible to define which users have access to what using something like: [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] without relying on AD i.e. specified within database table or within App itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.  You need to create a custom role provider that checks role memberships based on whatever you have on the back end.

The custom role provider derives from `System.Web.Security.RoleProvider`, and you need to override at least the `GetRolesForUser` and `IsUserInRole` methods.

The `GetRolesForUser` method is the one used by the `Authorize` attribute.  After the user is authenticated the attribute calls this method with the user's SamAccountName and expects the method to return a `string[]` containing the names of the roles the user is a member of.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74(v=vs.100).aspx for more details